# Z transform of $u(n)n$

Tags: complex-analysis

I know that the z transform of $u(n)$ is $\frac{z}{z-1}$ and z transform of $n$ is $\frac{z}{(z-1)^2}$. However i don't know how i can find the transform of their product

Comment: How do you define their product? Is $\{a_n\}\{b_n\} = \{a_n b_n\}$?

Comment: Try convolution in the Z domain since it's equivalent to multiplication in the n domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not correct. $x[n]=n$ has no z-transform since the following sum$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty nz^{-n}$$does not exist for $z\ne 0$.